# C# При копировании файла получаю пустой файл

Tags: c#

Помогите с проблемой. В учебных целях пишу небольшую программу на C# 
по работе с PDF, используя библиотеку ItextSharp 7. В одном из классов
пытаюсь скопировать файл для перезаписи используя `System.IO.File.Copy()`,
но в ответ получаю пустой файл. Что может быть не так ? Внятных ответов 
в Google я не нашел

Вот код класса:

```
string FilePath { get; set; }
int Rotation { get; set; }

// В этом методе проблема
void RotateFile()
{
    string dest = /* тут путь для сохранения */;

    if (FilePath != dest) // если файл назначения не совпадает с исходным, здесь все работает
    {
        if (File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            RotateThis(FilePath, dest);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Файл не существует или был перемещен!");
        }
    }                
    else if (FilePath == dest) // А вот здесь проблема
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo copier = new FileInfo(FilePath);
            if (!copier.Exists)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Файл не существует", "Ошибка!",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            string temp = Path.Combine(copier.DirectoryName, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMHHmmss") + "temp.pdf");

            if (Directory.Exists(copier.DirectoryName))
            {
                try
                {   // Вместо копирования, создает пустой файл
                    File.Copy(copier.FullName, temp, true);
                }
                catch (IOException exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка ввода-вывода при копировании во временный файл:" + 
                        exception.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при копировании во временный файл" + exc.Message);
                }

                try
                {
                    RotateThis(temp, FilePath);
                }
                catch (IOException exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка ввода-вывода при повороте документа:" + exception.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при повороте документа:" + exc.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    File.Delete(temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Файл не существует или был перемещен!", "Ошибка", 
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

void RotateThis(string src, string dest)
{
    try
    {
        using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest)))
        {
            int numberOfPages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
            try
            {
                for (int p = 1; p <= numberOfPages; p++)
                {
                    var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(p);
                    var rotate = page.GetPdfObject().GetAsNumber(PdfName.Rotate);
                    if (rotate == null)
                    {
                        page.SetRotation(Rotation);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        page.SetRotation((rotate.IntValue() + Rotation) % 360);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + exc.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                pdfDoc.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Завершено !","Готово",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка создания файла pdf: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: код программы приведите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Покажите [mcve]. Без него мы можем лишь гадать на кофейной гуще. Вдруг вы подавили исключения и копируете несуществующий файл?

Comment: Добавил код класса, без формы. Никаких исключений нет, но файл создается пустой.

Comment: Если у вас проблема в `File.Copy(copier.FullName, temp, true);`, укажите, чему равно `copier.FullName` и `temp`, и есть ли такие файлы на диске в этот момент.

Comment: copier.FullName равно С:\Users\Test\Desktop\src.pdf , temp равно С:\Users\Test\Desktop\1806083858temp.pdf . При вызове метода File.Copy(copier.FullName, temp, true); файл src.pdf существует, в временный файл ~temp.pdf должен создаться этим методом. Он и создается, только пустой.

Comment: @ThomasBacker: А вы точно уверены, что файл там нулевой? Попробуйте после `File.Copy` вставить `MessageBox`, во время которого посмотрите, появился ли файл и какой у него реально размер. Есть шанс, что файл «обрезается» позже, а `File.Copy` отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: @VladD: По вашему совету добавил: `FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo(temp); MessageBox.Show(tempFile.Exists + tempFile.Length.ToString());` после вызова File.Copy(); Показывает True  0. То есть файл существует, но размер его 0.

Comment: @ThomasBacker: Окей, а ещё можно вывести размер исходного файла тоже?

Comment: @VladD: True, 0. Размер исходного файла 56 кб

Comment: @ThomasBacker: нет, подождите, вы размер исходного файла тоже выведите в MessageBox.

Comment: @VlaD: Тоже пишет True, 0 .

Comment: @ThomasBacker: Вооооот! Я ж говорил, что чудес на свете не бывает. File.Copy не виноват. Ищите ошибку раньше.

Comment: @VladD: Выходит ошибка начинается вот здесь `FileInfo copier = new FileInfo(FilePath); ` То есть какая то ошибка с путем к файлу ? Но ведь файл существует, но его размер почему то становится равным нулю ...

Comment: @ThomasBacker: Ну вы передвиньте проверку размера файла вверх по тексту программы, пока не найдёте то место, где она _становится_ равной нулю.

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо вам ! А я осел ! У меня Handyman handyman = new Handyman();handyman.ViewSaveDialog();string dest = handyman.SavePathfile; А этот  SaveDialog создает Новый файл ! То есть я сам тупо перезаписываю исходный файл пустым ! Спасибо за помощь !

Comment: @ThomasBacker: Отлично, вот и разобрались! Пожалуйста!

Comment: @ThomasBacker: Тогда вопрос можно закрывать?

Comment: @VladD: Да, конечно. вопрос закрыт . File.Copy() работает как надо. Надо мне быть внимательнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодарю уважаемого VlaD за помощь в поиске настоящего источника проблемы.

Вопрос закрыт. Проблема была не в System.IO.File.Copy().

При вызове метода

```
Handyman handyman = new Handyman();
        handyman.ViewSaveDialog();
        string dest = handyman.SavePathfile;
```

Происходило создание нового файла , но так как я выбирал уже существующий исходный файл, он перезаписывался как пустой файл.System.IO.File.Copy() соответственно абсолютно правильно копировал пустой файл на пустой файл.